# WHat's the correct way to escape Javascript in Spring 4?

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, escaping

I recently upgraded to Spring `4.3.8.RELEASE`.  What's the correct way to escape JS on a JSP page?  I have this on my page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
...
var _currentId = "<spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${myId}</spring:escapeBody>";
```

but its resulting in this error ...

```
21:08:11,024 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myproject].[myprojectDispatcher]] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-12) Servlet.service() for servlet myprojectDispatcher threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EscapeBodyTag.setJavaScriptEscape(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Comment: Documentation shows it's still there. Perhaps in a different package? https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/EscapeBodyTag.html

Comment: Why does the package matter?  Is the taglib prefix different?

Comment: No, maybe in a different jar distribution - as in spring-webmvc.